# Remember selected value for next visits

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dropdown like this.

```
<select id='test'>
  <option value='one'>One</option>
  <option value='two'>Two</option>
  <option value='three'>Three</option>
 </select>
```

How can I show the selected value automatically at second time? First time it allows user to select an item from the drop down menu. But at second time it should show the previous selected value. How can I do this?

Comment: are you posting it as part of a form or are you wanting to store the value in a session?

Comment: define second time ?after postback

Comment: Try sessions, cookies or even HTML5 Local Storage.

Comment: devuser, you need to store the value somewhere, where is that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite broad, so I will give you a short list of options:

#Cookies

##Session
In php you can save user data in a file, that is affiliated with ID saved in session cookie. PHP does all the stuff for you, all you need to do is to use the `$_SESSION` variable.
Let this be the form:
**form.php**

```
<?php include "load.php";?>
<form action="save.php">
 <select id='test' name="select" method="post">
  <option value='one' 
       <?php if($_SESSION["sel"]=="one") echo "selected=\"selected\"";?>
  >One</option>
  <option value='two' <?php if(...=="two") echo ...;?>>Two</option>
  <option value='three' <?php ...?>>Three</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Now, initally, `$_SESSION` is not even defined, so we must load the data from session:

**load.php**

```
<?php
/**NO TEXT OUTPUT ABOVE THIS LINE!!!**/
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["sel"]))
   $_SESSION["sel"] = null;
?>
```

And this is where the form submits:

**save.php**

```
<?php
/**NO TEXT OUTPUT ABOVE THIS LINE!!!**/
session_start();
$_SESSION["sel"] = $_POST["select"];
?>
```

##Just cookies
Using just cookies allows user to change data anytime. This might be useful sometimes to handy users (but unfortunatelly for hackers too, if you're not careful).
PHP automatically generates `$_COOKIE` array with all the cookies that are stored in users browser. (better said: that the user has sent)
I won't make 3 file examples again, just see how cookies are created and deleted. Again, when setting a cookie, no output must come before the [`setcookie`](https://www.php.net/setcookie) call.

```
//Get a cookie
if($_COOKIE["sel"] == "two") {
    ... do something ...
}

//Set a cookie:
setcookie ("sel", $_POST["select"], time()+3600*24*7);  //Expires in 7 days

//Delete a cookie
setcookie ("sel", "", 0);  //Expired in 20th century
```

#[Local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)
This solution won't let your server know about user's setting. It might not be compatible with older browsers.
Local storage saves information on user's HDD without informing the remote server. Here's a menu that remembers it's selected value:

```
<select id='test' onchange="remember(this.selectedIndex);">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select something</option>
  <option value='one'>One</option>
  <option value='two'>Two</option>
  <option value='three'>Three</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(localStorage!=null) {
  if(localStorage["sel"]!=null) {
    document.getElementById("test").selectedIndex = localStorage["sel"];
  }
}
//alert("d");
function remember(index) {
  if(localStorage!=null) {
    localStorage["sel"] = index;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your option values in an array. Check if the value of `test` was `$_POST`ed. Create the select element. Iterate each array value to generate the `<option>`, check if the `$val` is the same as the `$_POST['test']` value. If it is, `echo 'selected'`. use `ucfirst` to capitalize the first letter.

```
$vals = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$selected = isset($_POST['test']) ? $_POST['test'] : false;

echo '<select id="test" name="test">';

foreach($vals as $val):
    echo '<option value="',$val,'" ', ($selected == $val) ? 'selected':'','>', ucfirst($val) ,'</option>';
endforeach;

echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Refracting my answer, I failed to see the "next visit" part.

The best way to do this assuming you are dealing with user accounts is to just store the selected option in the database and once the user logs in you can pull that selected option based on the username.

user->selected option->store in DB

user logs in->calls form->selected option pulled from DB

If you are not dealing with user accounts then you will have to set a cookie to remember the person and their selection for the next time they visit.

see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_cookies.htm

Answer (score 0):

This Typescript will store any select boxes tagged with a class "remember" into local storage.

i.e.

```html
<select class='remember'>
  <option value='one'>One</option>
  <option value='two'>Two</option>
  <option value='three'>Three</option>
</select>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('select.remember').forEach((elem) => {
    if(elem instanceof HTMLSelectElement) {
        // Restore from local storage
        const selectedIndex = localStorage.getItem(elem.name)
        if(selectedIndex) {
            elem.selectedIndex = parseInt(selectedIndex)
        }
        // Add a click handler
        elem.addEventListener("change", () => {
            localStorage.setItem(elem.name, '' + elem.selectedIndex)
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to set the selected attribute.

Comment: That isn't very helpful at all.